# Accessing ParseFieldName Property from outside

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I have a parse subclass like:

```
[ParseClassName("_User")]
public class RFUser : ParseUser
{
    [ParseFieldName("firstname")]
    public string Firstname
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty(value); }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to read the ParseFieldName ("firstname") from other parts of the program?

Something like: 
typeof(RFUser).ParseFieldNames.Firstname ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. The ParseClassName and ParseFieldName attributes appear to be custom attributes. If so, you can access them if you get the name of the property  that is set by the attribute's constructor.

Because I do not have (or don't know I have) the DLL that defines the `ParseFieldName` attribute's class, I created it as follows:

```
public class ParseFieldName: Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ParseFieldName(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

For reference, my `RFUser` class is defined as:

```
[ParseClassName("_User")]
public class RFUser
{
    [ParseFieldName("fieldfirstname")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
}
```

Elsewhere in the program, I have a class with a `using System.Reflection` statement and that has a method containing the following code snippet:

```
RFUser user = new RFUser();
var attribute = (ParseFieldName)user.GetType().GetProperty("Firstname").GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ParseFieldName));
Console.WriteLine(attribute.Name);
```

The value displayed in the console is `fieldfirstname`.

You can also access regular attributes if you substitute `Attributes` for `GetCustomAttributes()`.